# Floating Draggable view for Android without using permissions(SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)

Tags: android, android-studio, draggable, floating

I want to show a draggable view floating on my activities.
I do not want to ask user for permission like

User should be able to interact with activity while the draggable view is open.

The draggable view should not disappear user go to next activities.
Instead, user can manually close the view(eg: by clicking on the cross icon on the view).

I am able to create a draggable view and able to interact with it, at the same time with the activity which is in foreground. but when I go to the other activity, the view closes.

Comment: "The draggable view should not disappear user go to next activities" -- then only have one activity. Use fragments or composables for the individual screens.

Comment: But that is not the case. If user goes from Activity A to Activity B the view draggable view should still be visible, and if some video is playing in that view then the video should continue playing.@CommonsWare

Comment: "But that is not the case" -- I am suggesting that you should change your UI so it *is* the case. Rewrite your UI to have only one activity. Otherwise, what you seek is not possible AFAIK, without asking for the permission that you do not want to ask for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer@CommonsWare. Will look into it more. But UI can't be changed.

Comment: "But UI can't be changed" -- if you can add code to an activity to show a draggable window, then you are changing the UI.